# Second scanf in this code will just not read. (C-code)

Tags: c, double, scanf

I just came back to C and after all the searching I did, I didn't come up with a working solution for this Code:

```
double a = 0, c = 0;
printf("Please enter 2 numbers! Number 1: \n");
scanf(" %d", &a); 

printf("Please enter number 2 now!\n");     
scanf(" %d", &c);  /*This scanf is problematic*/
printf("Thank you! The numbers you have entered are %i and %i", a, c);
```

The second `scanf` (with or without whitespace) does not read any number but instead gives out the 0 that it was initialized with. The first `scanf` works just fine. I hope I just overlooked something, but I have tried for several errors.

Comment: `%d` is for scanning ints not doubles. try printing the number you just scanned - it's probably not what you expect...

Comment: You are reading with an integer format specifier into double variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to change `%i` and `%d` to `%lf` like this:

```
double a=0, c=0;

printf("Please enter 2 numbers! Number 1: \n");

scanf(" %lf", &a);

printf("Please enter number 2 now!\n");

scanf(" %lf", &c);

printf("Thank you! The numbers you have entered are %lf and %lf", a, c);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!
Do you have a short explanation or link?

Comment: @Jordan181 Maybe this helps you as reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Short explanation: `%lf` is the correct format specifier for type `double`.  `%d` and `%c` are not.